# Как узнать кто заблокировал моего бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-3.8

Есть бот. Нужно,чтобы при блокировке бота юзером,в бот выходило сообщение,что бот заблокирован каким-то пользователем и чтобы бот выполнил определенную функцию. Пишу на python , библиотека telebot, база данных SQL

Comment: при отправке сообщения от имени бота пользователю который заблокировал бота будет получено `Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user`, один из вариантов обрабатывать такие сообщения. либо смотреть в дебаге что происходит при блокировки бота пользователем.

Comment: В том то и дело,я не знаю как обработать такое сообщение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример отправки и обработки ошибок на `requests`:

```
def send(token, USER_ID, ADM_ID):
    try:
            r = requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage', data={'chat_id': USER_ID, 'text': 'q1349229'})
            if r.status_code == 200:
                pass
            else:
                requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage',
                              data={'chat_id': ADM_ID, 'text': 'Ошибка отправки' + '\n' + 'id: ' + str(USER_ID) + '\n' + str(r.json()['description'])})
    except Exception as error:
        requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage', data={'chat_id': ADM_ID, 'text': 'Exception отправки' + '\n' + str(error)})
```

- если код ответа на запрос (`requests.post`) 200 - продолжаем
- иначе отправляем администратору (ADM_ID) сообщение "Ошибка отправки id: пользователя (USER_ID) c описанием ошибки (`r.json()['description'])}`)"
- в случае исключения (Exception) отправляем администратору (ADM_ID) сообщение "Exception отправки с описанием ошибки (`error`)"

UPD: пример на telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    try:
        bot.send_message(123, 'test')
    except Exception as error:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, re.search(r'Description:\s(.*)', str(error)).group(1))


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Примеры:

> Ошибка отправки id: 20***18 Bad Request: chat not found
>
> Ошибка отправки id: 94***66 Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user

Comment: c вами можно связать в телеграм например?

Comment: Просто не совсем понял,как это внедрить в мой код

Comment: напишите свой ник в Telegram